# Is it possible to detect if fluent interface was called for the first time?

Tags: java, fluent-interface

Let's say I have a class:

```
class A {
    public A fun() {
        System.out.println("a");
        return this;
    }   
}
```

And a scenario:

```
A a = new A();
a.fun().fun().fun().fun();
a.fun().fun();
```

Is it somehow possible to print additional message in the first call of each sequenced calls without adding something like `.start()`/`.finalize()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
public class A {

    public A fun() {
        System.out.println("A");
        return new AA();
    }

    private class AA extends A {
        @Override
        public A fun() {
            System.out.println("AA");
            return this;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        a.fun();
        a.fun().fun();
        a.fun().fun().fun();
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
A
A
AA
A
AA
AA
```

Comment: Wow :D And here I thought I dreamed too deep. Nice one.